# How can I add a voltage source like these in LTspice?

Tags: voltage, current, ltspice, simulation

[image]

Do you know how I can make these in LTspice?

Comment: Good thing they added dots at the test points, but not at junctions. That's a poorly drawn schematic, because it can be interpreted that `R1` is in series with `R2`, and they have no intersection with `C1` going into the base of the transistor (e.g. the wires do not touch). Please tell your teacher about this, it can be a serious cause for misinterpretation.

Answer (score 7):

These aren't voltage **sources**, they are just named voltages in the circuit. You don't add anything to the circuit.

The + and - marks just show you the two points in the circuit where the voltage is measured. In this case, both voltages will be measured with respect to ground.

In LTspice you should label the wires with "Vi" and "Vo" at the points marked with the + sign.

Comment: +1 Hit F4 to enter the net name then stick it on a wire.

Comment: @ElliotAlderson  What should I do if I want to give a value for Vi?

Comment: @Mert you could add a voltage source across the terminals if you want to force the voltage there to a specific value. But that will change the behavior of the circuit. Notice that if you use \$R_s=0\$ as indicated in your schematic, then the \$V_s\$ supply is already forcing the voltage at \$V_i\$.

Comment: @Mert:  those are test points where you measure the voltage - you don't apply a voltage there.

Comment: @ThePhoton yes, but Rs is changing in other question.

Comment: @Mert in those questions, forcing the voltage by applying a voltage source is not likely to get you the correct answer.